# Changing List Entry Syntax

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that creates a small GUI for a function.  In particular, I have something like this:

```
def create_widgets(self):
    self.entryLabel = Label(self, text="Please enter a list of numbers:")
    self.entryLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)      

    self.listEntry = Entry(self)
    self.listEntry.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)

    self.entryLabel = Label(self, text="Please enter an index value:")
    self.entryLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=E)

    self.indexEntry = Entry(self)
    self.indexEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)

    self.runBttn = Button(self, text="Run Function", command=self.Function)
    self.runBttn.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

    self.answerLabel = Label(self, text="Output List:")
    self.answerLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
```

Then for the definition of the function I have a part afterwards:

```
    self.answer = Label(self, text=rtn)
    self.answer.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
```

that tells it what to give as output.

Now, the issue is the input is entered as a string (say 12345) and so it would recognize the numbers 10,11,12 and so on as their individual digits.  Is there a simple way to modify this to require list inputs to be comma delimited (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends upon what you mean by "require". For example, do you want the application to reject invalid input and show a message saying, "please separate numbers by commas"? In general, that's not possible, because the input `12345` is just as valid as `1,2,3,4,5`. You can't determine whether the user forgot the commas, or really meant twelve thousand three hundred and forty five, unless there are additional constraints you haven't told us like "the user must supply exactly five numbers"

Comment: @Kevin My apologies for the late response.  I'm not sure if you're still around now. I suppose it doesn't have to be commas even, but the idea is that there needs to be a way for it to known 10111213 means 10,11,12,13.

Comment: But how _do_ you know that 10111213 means 10,11,12,13? Maybe it means 101, 112, 1, 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just asking how to turn `"1,2,3,4,5"` into a list of integers, you can do it with [`split`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) and [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

```
user_input = "4,8,15,16,23,42"
numbers = [int(d) for d in user_input.split(",")]

print "numbers:", numbers
print "sum of numbers:", sum(numbers)
```

Result:

```
numbers: [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
sum of numbers: 108
```

Comment: Would split input allow it to recognize that 1011 is just 10,11?  In fact I should give a more complex example:  112233445511 should be 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,11.  Sorry if I'm still not being entirely clear.

Comment: If `user_input` is the string `"1011"`, the numbers list will be `[1011]`. If `user_input` is the string `"10,11"`, the numbers list will be `[10, 11]`.

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  How is the reconciled with your very good point above: that we have no way to know that a long string is to be read the 'right way' and not as 101, 112, 1, 3. Also would I put this somewhere in self.listEntry?  Thanks again for your help.